# Appending the list to the base list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `J`. I am removing elements according to `index` but I also want to append the new list to the base list `J`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
J = [[2, 6, 9, 10]]
index = [[0, 3]]

J = [j for i,j in enumerate(J[0]) if i not in index[0]]
print(J.append(J))
```

The current output is

```
None
```

The expected output is

```
[[2, 6, 9, 10],[6, 9]]
```

Comment: `a.append(b)` modifies `a` and returns `None`. `a + b` does not modify `a`, and returns a new value. Also, you overwrite `J`, so you can't concatenate with the original value, it is gone. `K = [j for ...]; print(J + K)` will do what you want.

Comment: Try printing `J` rather than the output of the `append` list method, which is just `None` as you've seen.  Don't put it in the `print` call.  Try `J.append(J)` followed by `print(J)`.  But if you append `J` to itself, you will end up with a self-referential list, so you won't be able to print it (it will show the self-reference as an ellipsis, i.e. `...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
J = [[2, 6, 9, 10]]
index = [0, 3]

new_J = [j for i, j in enumerate(J[0]) if i not in index]
J.append(new_J)
print(J)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
J=[[2, 6, 9, 10]]
baseJ = J[0].copy()
index=[[0,3]]

for i in range(len(index[0])):
    baseJ.pop(index[0][i] - i)
    
J.append(baseJ)
print(J)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through the values of the new list in a for loop?

```py
J = [[2, 6, 9, 10]]
index = [[0, 3]]

for i in index:
  J.append(I)
```

Sorry if this isn't what you wanted!